# how to make my hero image in css clickable?

Tags: html

i am currently studying web development and i'm practicing my html and css.
i created a page where the divs go on top of each other through css.
to accomplish that, i learned i can put the background image in css.
here's a prototype of my hero image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtBp8.png)

i want the 3 bottles on the left to be clickable. i'd like to have each bottle when clicked to take me to a div. is that possible?

thanks in advance

```css
.section {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.secOne {
  background-image: url("../img/finbluehero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionOne {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000B29;
}

.secTwo {
  background-image: url("../img/finredhero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionTwo {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #D70026;
}

.secThree {
  background-image: url("../img/finyellowhero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionThree {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #edb83d;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f8f5f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="section secOne"></div>
  <div class="sub_sectionOne"></div>
  <div class="section secTwo"></div>
  <div class="sub_sectionTwo"></div>
  <div class="section secThree"></div>
  <div class="sub_sectionThree"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: did the solution posted work?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

You can do this pretty easily by wrapping the `div` containing your image with an `anchor` tag. The `href` attribute can be set to the link that you want to redirect to.

```css
.section {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.secOne {
  background-image: url("../img/finbluehero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionOne {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000B29;
}

.secTwo {
  background-image: url("../img/finredhero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionTwo {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #D70026;
}

.secThree {
  background-image: url("../img/finyellowhero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionThree {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #edb83d;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f8f5f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <a href="link_to_wherever">
    <div class="section secOne"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="sub_sectionOne"></div>
  <a href="link_to_wherever">
    <div class="section secTwo"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="sub_sectionTwo"></div>
  <a href="link_to_wherever">
    <div class="section secThree"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="sub_sectionThree"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the snippet, it only appears as a background color

Comment: @Swellar that's because the `image` is on the author's local machine. :/

Comment: At least provide a web image for better result. As it is, it looks like it is doing nothing

Comment: thank you for the replies guys. can you please show me how i can make a part of an image clickable? i have 3 bottles in the picture and i wish to accomplish when i click a certain bottle, it will take me to the divs. hope that makes sense. very similar to html map tag where i can add coordinates. but since my img is set in (as a) background-image in css, is it still possible to put the coordinates to define the clickable space of each bottle?